# Typescript regex to include only letters after =

Tags: regex

I am using regex expression in typescript to match a certain string and get the desired output. But I am facing some difficulties.
I basically want to match all the letters after equals sign, and also it shouldn't match words/letters that start with a backslash ( \ )

Here is an example of what I want-

Input:

```
d = \\sqrt{w^2 + l^2}
```

Output:

```
[w, l]
```

This is what I have written till now, it deals with almost everything I need, I just don't know how can I make it so that it doesn't match anything before equal (=) sign.

```
regex = /(?<!\\)\b(?!\\?\.)(\w+)/g
```

With the above expression, the output I am getting is `[d, w, 2, l, 2]`

*Note: The input string will be dynamic, so I can't include specific characters in the regex expression to not include.*

Comment: Your statement is untrue. Here's what you're getting with the regex you use: https://regex101.com/r/OsD7IC/1 and the matches are nothing like `[A, w, l]`

Comment: Yes that's my bad, I accidentally wrote the output for the input string `A = l \cdot w` .
I edited my question and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one positive look behind and one negative look behind for `=` and `\` respectively and this regex should work,

```
(?<==.*)(?<!\\)\b[a-zA-Z]+
```

```js
const s = 'd = \\sqrt{w^2 + l^2}';

const reg = /(?<==.*)(?<!\\)\b[a-zA-Z]+/g;

console.log(s.match(reg));
```